# what is this material for?

Tags: texturing

I'm trying to port a model from sfm to blender and after decompiling i found some textures i've never seen before. What are they for and how to apply such textures? Also every texture called "eye-cornea", so it seems they are related to eyes  [image]

Comment: Is it not a normal map? Except it doesn't seem very useful here are there doesn't seem to have any information

Comment: Other textures had prefix _n for normal map, but these doesn't have any prefix so i didn't even think they could be  normal maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The cornea is the transparent front part of the eye that covers the iris, pupil, and anterior chamber
>
> [image: Eye Cornea]
>
> (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornea)

So my guess would be that you have found the normal map responsible for creating an apparent bump in the front of the eye.